# node application give proxy error when in production mode

Tags: node.js, apache

I have a mean.js app which I've deployed to my production server.
it worked well when I had it in development mode, but since I switched it to production mode I'm getting a 502 proxy error.
the same happens whether I run it with node server.js or pm2.

I'm running on linux/debian with apache2.
I a newbie in this environment, how do I find the problem.

Comment: Hey Igal, nice to bump into you here.
I think you'll get more help if you'll elaborate more on your problem. What web-server are you using? What differences can you think of exist between your dev and prod environment? These details can be crucial for solving the problem.

Comment: It's likely because something blew up in your node app, or apache isn't configured properly. If you do `node server.js` do you see anything in the output that would indicate a problem? If not, maybe take a look at a tutorial for using apache in front of node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an SSL issue.
in my production.js file I commented the following:

```
module.exports = {
  //secure: {
  //  ssl: false,
  //  privateKey: './config/sslcerts/key.pem',
  //  certificate: './config/sslcerts/cert.pem'
  //},
...
```

this is of course a temp solution until the application really goes live